# RegEx to extract string between chars and excluding the chars Angular Typescript

Tags: regex, typescript

I have a string pattern like

```
var str = "@#[test][some desc]@#@#[test1][some desc for test2]@#"
```

I need to extract string between the chars `(first @# and @# and again [ and ])` using regex.

I have tried below regex

```
/@#(.+?)@#/g
```

which gives me the result `@#[test][some desc]@# and @#[test1][some desc for test2]@#`

Here I wanted to exclude the `@#` also.

Help me to write a regex which gives me the result in an `array`.

The `variable array` which will have 2 elements and each element will have only

```
test
some desc

test1
some desc for test2
```

Pls help with the `regex` in `typescript`.

Comment: Whoever came up with this godawful format should be forced to solve your problem.

Comment: Please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60000481/3832970): I use a single regex to parse the strings in your format.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
/@#\[([^\]]*)]\[([^\]]*)]@#/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/62pI1P/1)

**Details**

- `@#\[` - `@#[` substring
- `([^\]]*) - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than`]`
- `]\[` - `][` substring
- `([^\]]*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `]`
- `]@#` - a  `]@#` substring.

JS demo:

```js
var regex = /@#\[([^\]]*)]\[([^\]]*)]@#/g;
var s = "@#[test][some desc]@#@#[test1][some desc for test2]@#";
var m, res = [];
while (m = regex.exec(s)) {
  res.push([m[1], m[2]]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know typescript but I think is similar to JS:

```
var str = "@#[test][some desc]@#@#[test1][some desc for test2]@#";

var a = str.match(/@#([^@#]+)@#/g);
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
{
    var d = a[i].match(/\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]/);
    console.log(d[1], d[2]);
}
```

output:

```
test some desc
test1 some desc for test2
```